# Import custom database in wordpress with custom user type, custom post type and all other fields

Tags: sql, database, wordpress

I have an old website which want to do it in wordpress. So I want to import old website's database in new website which I am doing in wordpress.

I have custom roles with custom fields in old and new website
Also have Custom post-types and each post-type have it's custom fields

In both websites is fully same but old website is not on wordpress and I want website on wordpress

Is there any better way to import old website's databsase in new website?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your old site is html only? If so, you can download the entire site's pages with a tool like HTTrack. You can then take each page and upload it into your new site manually via ftp.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Old website is a dynamic website with php and SQL, not html only. Old website have data like some user roles and their permission and with user role who can add post, edit post etc. I need to bring that website on wordpress. This is main thing.